# jQuery Working on IE7 standards but not on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am working with twitter bootstrap. Twitter bootstrap along with jQuery cycle and jQuery Carousel is not working with IE8. But when I put the browser in the compatibility mode with IE7 standards it is working. I am not able to find out y that happens. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please define "not working". Tell us what is happening; don't make us guess. Also, what have you done to try to isolate the problem and work it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to look at the demos on their site, does it work with IE8? Also check if you get any javascript error in console...

Comment: In case you are not aware you can press F12 to display the IE developer tools, just like the other browsers ;) This will give you access to the console and you can also set breakpoints, watches, etc in your JS code.

Comment: @vrocipes This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were likely running into the same issue I did with the jQuery css intepreter issue in ie8 Standards mode that breaks when there is a duplicate entry in the css.  There must be a difference in the way that jquery..css("border-left-width") responds in ie8 Standards Mode as the following css renders correctly in ie7 and ie9 Standards Modes, but not in ie8 Standard Mode:

```
 table {
 border: 8px solid #C2DDEE;
 border: none;
}
```